# Finding IDLE in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I am running python 3.3.5. I can't figure out how to launch the IDLE IDE. I installed everything correctly but the IDLE doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: You might want to add the `python-3.x` or `python-3.3` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

To start it from the command line in Python 3.3+:

```
$ python3 -midlelib
```

Or in the code:

```
import idlelib.PyShell
idlelib.PyShell.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find an idle.py file at `C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib`.

There are 2 `idle.py`s file and both of them work. The first opens a command prompt alongside idle and the other doesn't.